# How change the shape of a node in a tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code.

I want to create a tikz matrix which contain nodes with predefined default shapes.

Yet sometimes I want to change some node's shapes specifying it manually inside of the matrix.

I read in the tikz manual that any code that is written in front of a node's text with vertical lines gets passed to the node's code.

Thus the code: Should be passed to the code of the second Joe Doe node.

`|(shape = rectangle)|`

Running this don't seem to work though.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(a)[
  matrix of nodes, 
  nodes in empty cells, 
  nodes={draw, circle, align=center, text width=0.8cm},
  column sep={1.5cm, between origins}, 
  row sep={1.5cm, between origins}
]{
  & John \linebreak Doe &[5cm]|(shape = rectangle)| John \linebreak Doe& \\[2cm]
  & & &\\
};

\draw[->] (a-1-1) -- (a-2-1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `[shape=rectangle]` (square brackets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong delimiters! Use square brackets `[]` to add/override node options:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(a)[
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes in empty cells,
  nodes={draw, circle, align=center, text width=0.8cm},
  column sep={1.5cm, between origins},
  row sep={1.5cm, between origins}
]{
  & John \linebreak Doe &[5cm]|[rectangle]| John \linebreak Doe& \\[2cm]
  & & &\\
};
\draw[->] (a-1-1) -- (a-2-1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]